# ui cant find the js loaded under a different space

Tags: angularjs

This is the code I used to load the external js transaction-element

```
     addTransactionElement() {
      this.http.get<any>('../transaction/transactionUrl').subscribe((res) => {
          const link = this.renderer.createElement('link');
          link.rel = 'stylesheet';
          link.href = 'http://localhost:8083/elements/assets/fonts/webadk-icon-font.css';
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, link);

          const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          this.renderer.setAttribute(script, 'crossorigin', 'true');  
          script.src = 'http://localhost:8083/transaction-element.js';
          script.text = ``;
          this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, script);
      });
  }
```

I can see it loaded though under a different space, localhost:8083, where the element.js is hosted. My own ui space is hosted under localhost:4200.
[image]

This is code to render it.

```
      <transaction-element
          businessLine="{{ transactionInfo.businessLine }}"
          theme="{{ transactionTheme }}"
      ></transaction-element>
```

It does not happen. No error messages anywhere. Is it because the external element.js is uploaded under a different space? If so, anyway to correct it?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing ` script.src = 'http://localhost:8083/...` to ` script.src = 'http://localhost:4200`